# How to read values from multiple textboxes in a row?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, oledbconnection

I have to insert the date(label), the activity name(label) and the value entered into database. 
I have the following code:

```
 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command= new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection= connection;
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DoctorActivity_10(Duty_Date,DutyType,Cases) values ("?","?","?");

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();



}
```

If I do not have a specific textbox and I have to read various textboxes to see in which textbox data is entered. What should I put in the query? Please refer to the image I have put to get a better understanding.[image added from link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GLbl.png)

Comment: You should always try to use parameter in your queries to prevent attacks from SQL injection.
e.g. Insert into DoctorActivity_10(DutyDate,DutyType,Cases) values (@DutyDate, @DutyType, @Cases)
Then add values to your command for these parameters before you execute it: 
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@DutyDate",<DateValue>);

Comment: What have you tried to get the data from the controls? Are the controls in an array or have a standard naming convention? Most importantly, do you have the option to re-design? My eyes hurt ...

Comment: @RyanPeters I would redesign this. But this is the format I have to keep for some reasons. The controls have a series of standard names.

Comment: @GLewis I have to fetch the DateValue from the respective row in which the text has been entered.

Comment: How do you create the textboxes that you are displaying?

Comment: @GLewis I am sorry I didn't get you. I used design view to create them.

Comment: I was wondering whether you had created them dynamically or not. But it seems as though you have placed each one individually on the screen?